# sorting vector of strings in c++ according to index in the string

Tags: c++

Hi I have vector of strings,that is the structure of vector : The name of vector is vector

```
"key:  abc 165.123.34.12", 
"key:  bca 1.1.1.1", 
"key1: bac 3.3.3.3"
```

I want to sort the vector according to the second field(abc,bac,bac)

My code is;

```
 bool sort_function(string& str1,string& str2) {

     string nick1,nick2,nick1_ignore,nick2_ignore;

     stringstream ss1(str1) 

     ss1>> nick1_ignore >> nick1;

     stringstream ss2(str2) 

     ss2>> nick2_ignore >> nick2;

     return (nick1<nick2);

 }


     sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(),sort_function);
```

But it gives a long error starting with error,

```
  error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>
```

UPDATE:Error is tl_algo.h: In function ‘_RandomAccessIterator std:..

UPDATE:It is fixed. the error is in function declaration I have to use const string

Comment: #include <string>/#include <sstream> ?

Comment: I don't think I understand the logic of your sort_function. What is it supposed to do with that stringstream?

Comment: @ForEver both of them are included

Comment: @MihaiTodor: The stringstream is extracting the second word from each string, so these can be compared.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Hm... I had no idea it can tokenize strings based on spaces. Nice functionality. Is there any way to change the token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function template overload `operator>>(std::basic_istream &, std::string &)` is non-`const` on its `istream` parameter, so you can't call it on a temporary.

This is confusing, because you *can* call the member `operator>>` when reading a primitive e.g. `int`.

Instead, you'll have to write

```
stringstream ss1(str1); ss1 >> nick1_ignore >> nick1;
```

You could also work around this by first reading a no-op manipulator or calling a no-op method to get an lvalue reference:

```
stringstream(str1).ignore(0) >> nick1_ignore >> nick1;
```

C++11 fixes this by providing overloads of the free `operator>>` with the `istream` parameter an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `std::istringstream` for this sort of thing.  If the
lines really have the format you describe, something along the lines of:

```
class CompareFields
{
    int myStart;
    int myEnd;
public:
    CompareFields( int start, int end )
        : myStart( start )
        , myEnd( end )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs ) const
    {
        assert( lhs.size() >= myEnd && rhs.size() >= myEnd );
        return std::lexicographical_compare( lhs.begin() + myStart,
                                             lhs.begin() + myEnd,
                                             rhs.begin() + myStart,
                                             rhs.begin() + myEnd );
    }
};
```

should be all that's needed:

```
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), CompareFields( 6, 9 ) );
```

If you want to define the fields differently; e.g. as white space,
you'll need to redefine `CompareFields` so that it does the right thing.